# Código para visualização do BoxPlot no ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

na visualização dos boxplot criados com o script abaixo, não me parece que os gráficos `g2, g3` e `g4` são os mesmos que aparecem na imagem `g1`, mas não consegui encontrar nada errado no código! Vejam que os limites da mediana ou o máximo e mínimo dos gráficos estão diferentes! O `gamma1` por exemplo no gráfico `g1` está acima do valor `0.5` no eixo `y` e no gráfico `g2` está abaixo deste valor!

```
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
n=100
#N=100
m=matrix(ncol=8,nrow=n)
for(i in 1:n){
  m[i,] <- runif(8)
}

parametros = factor(rep(c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0", "beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho"), each=n))
df <- data.frame(parametros, val_Sim = c(m[,1],m[,2],m[,3],m[,4],m[,5],m[,6],m[,7],m[,8]))
d <- df %>% group_by(parametros,val_Sim)

g1 <- ggplot(d, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") + 
  xlab("Parâmetros")+ 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Valores Estimados",
                   labels=c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0", "beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

parametros = factor(rep(c("gamma0", "gamma1","gamma2"), each=n))
df <- data.frame(parametros, val_Sim = c(m[,1],m[,2],m[,3]))
d <- df %>% group_by(parametros,val_Sim)


g2 <- ggplot(d, aes(y = d$val_Sim, x = parametros)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") + 
  xlab("Parâmetros") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

g1
g2
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(g1,g2)

parametros = factor(rep(c("beta0","beta1", "beta2"), each=n))
df <- data.frame(parametros, val_Sim = c(m[,4],m[,5],m[,6]))
d <- df %>% group_by(parametros,val_Sim)

g3 <- ggplot(d, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") + 
  xlab("Parâmetros") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

parametros = factor(rep(c("phi1", "rho"), each=n))
df <- data.frame(parametros, val_Sim = c(m[,7],m[,8]))
d <- df %>% group_by(parametros,val_Sim)
means <- aggregate(val_Sim ~  parametros, df, mean)

g4 <- ggplot(d, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") + 
  xlab("Parâmetros") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-1.25, 1.25, 0.25),
                     limits=c(-1.25, 1.25))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

grid.arrange(g1,g3)

grid.arrange(g1,g4)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O problema está na ordem dos fatores do eixo x do objeto `d`. O gráfico `g1` com o teu código é assim:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
n=100
#N=100
m=matrix(ncol=8,nrow=n)
for(i in 1:n){
  m[i,] <- runif(8)
}

parametros = factor(rep(c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0", "beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho"), each=n))
df <- data.frame(parametros, val_Sim = c(m[,1],m[,2],m[,3],m[,4],m[,5],m[,6],m[,7],m[,8]))
d <- df %>% group_by(parametros,val_Sim)

g1_original <- ggplot(d, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") + 
  xlab("Parâmetros")+ 
  scale_x_discrete(name = "Valores Estimados",
                   labels=c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0", "beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho")) + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

g1_original
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acontece que os beta e os gamma estão trocados. O `ggplot2` não entende a função `scale_x_discrete` neste teu caso. O gráfico correto é este abaixo, que bate com a tua descoberta analisando o gráfico `g2`:

```
g1_editado <- ggplot(d, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") + 
  xlab("Parâmetros")+ 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

g1_editado
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para obter a ordem que tu deseja, com os beta antes dos gamma, transforme a coluna `parametros` em fator, com sua ordem especificada de acordo com a tua vontade:

```
d$parametros <- factor(d$parametros, 
  levels = c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0",       
  "beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho"), ordered = TRUE)

g1_ideal <- ggplot(d, aes(y = val_Sim, x = parametros)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = parametros),alpha = .6,size = .5)+ 
  stat_boxplot(geom ='errorbar') +
  guides(fill=FALSE)+geom_point()+
  ggtitle("Boxplot com os valores estimados") + 
  xlab("Parâmetros") + 
  scale_y_continuous(name = "Valores Estimados",
                     breaks = seq(-0.5, 2, 0.5),
                     limits=c(-0.5, 2))+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

g1_ideal
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Basta seguir a lógica do `g1` para resolver os outros problemas similares a este que surgirem.

Answer (score 2):

Outra forma de resolver é trocar a parte do meu código do gráfico `g1` onde está escrito:

`scale_x_discrete(name = "Valores Estimados",
                   labels=c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0", "beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho")) +`

por:

`scale_x_discrete(limits=c("gamma0","gamma1","gamma2","beta0", "beta1","beta2","phi1", "rho")) +`